# Heroku Rails Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku

I got a 500 Internal Sever error when I try to deploy my rails app on heroku.  It works fine on my local machine, so i'm not sure what's wrong here.  Seems to be something with the "sessions" on the home controller.  Here is my log:

```
==> production.log <==
# Logfile created on Sun May 09 17:35:59 -0700 2010

Processing HomeController#index (for 76.169.212.8 at 2010-05-09 17:36:00) [GET]

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  relation "sessions" does not ex
ist
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a
.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"sessions"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
):
  lib/authenticated_system.rb:106:in `login_from_session'
  lib/authenticated_system.rb:12:in `current_user'
  lib/authenticated_system.rb:6:in `logged_in?'
  lib/authenticated_system.rb:35:in `authorized?'
  lib/authenticated_system.rb:53:in `login_required'
  /home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'
  /home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:25:in `call'
  /home/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `catch'
  thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
  thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
  thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'
  thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start'
  thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'
  thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `send'
  thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
  thin (1.2.7) lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
  thin (1.2.7) bin/thin:6
  /usr/local/bin/thin:20:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/thin:20

Rendering /disk1/home/slugs/155328_f2d3c00_845e/mnt/public/500.html (500 Interna
l Server Error)
```

And here is my home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :login_required

    def index
        @user = current_user
        @user.profile ||= Profile.new
    @profile = @user.profile
    end

end
```

Does it have something the way my routes are set up? Or is it my authentication? (I am using restful authentication with Bort)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your app seems to be looking for a sessions table.

Have you run all of your migrations?

Sometimes it can help to use **heroku db:push** to ensure that your database is the same locally and remote.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you forgot to `heroku rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

Also, `heroku rake db:sessions:create`. Create your sessions table.

Migrate too.
 `heroku rake db:migrate` Cheers! :)